# Uncaught ReferenceError: (function) is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search form where I'm trying to have it output the results at the bottom of the page without reloading.

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<div id="search-form">      
<input type="text" name="search" class="search-field" id="search" value="" />
<div class="submit-container">
<button type="button" value="" class="submit" id="searchbutton" onclick="searchoutput()" /></button>
            </div>
  </form>
  <br><br>
  <p>Type First Name</p>
```

I want the search results to show below when the button is clicked, using Ajax call to another script. I keep getting an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: searchoutput is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Here is my javascript (using jquery):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
function searchoutput() {
     if($(".search-field").val().length > 5) { //only shows results when more than 5 characters have been entered
        var search = $(".search-field").val();
        var update = $(".result");
        var goal = 0;
        $.get("query-include.php" , {search: search, goal: goal})
        .done(function( data ) {
          update.empty();
          update.append(data);
          $(this).remove();
                                });
                                             };
                         } 
  $( ".search-field" ).keydown(function() {
      var update =$(".results");
      update.empty();
                                       });
                             });
```

I have checked other posts and spent a long time trying to get the solution on my own. The odd thing is if I add an event listener for "keyup" in order to run the same function searchoutput as the user types:

```
var searchfield = document.getElementById("search");
searchfield.addEventListener("keyup", searchoutput);
```

Then I don't get the ReferenceError and the script runs fine.. I only get the function issue on button click.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a scoping issue - `searchOutput` is defined within the scope of the `$(document).ready()` function. What you could try is to declare a var for `searchOutput` before that code, then assign it to the function like this:

```
var searchOutput;
$( document ).ready(function() {
  searchOutput = function () {
   if($(".search-field").val().length > 5) {
   //etc.
```

Comment: The problem now though is the keyup eventlistener no longer fires. I think because of how you changed line 3 in your example to assign a function to the searchoutput variable.. whereas the eventlistener keyup runs the searchoutput function.. now it can no longer find that function. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: oh gotcha - where does `addEventListener` get called?

Comment: on the first line after document ready, just above the function

Comment: have you tried moving the `addEventListener` down to after where the searchoutput function is defined?

Comment: That works. Thank you. I guess I need a lot more practice with scoping and the order of items

Answer (score 0):

I add an eventListener in the place of searchoutput();

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.submit').addEventListener('click', function(){
     if($(".search-field").val().length > 5) { //only shows results when more than 5 characters have been entered
        var search = $(".search-field").val();
        var update = $(".result");
        var goal = 0;
        $.get("query-include.php" , {search: search, goal: goal})
        .done(function( data ) {
          update.empty();
          update.append(data);
          $(this).remove();
         
                                });
                                             }
                         });
  $( ".search-field" ).keydown(function() {
      var update =$(".results");
      update.empty();
                                       });
                             });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
I was using modular code in my JS (i.e. import and export statements) so when I tried to use `onclick`, it wasn't calling my `submit` function. When I simply removed the import statement from my JS code and replaced dependent code with some default values, `onclick` called my function. Then I tried the `addEventListener` with `import/export` and finally it worked for me.